# Dynamic route url change is not reflecting in laravel package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-routing, laravel-testing

I am creating a package which gives a config file to customize the route url which it will add, I can see config file values in the controller, but same `config('app_settings.url')` is coming as `null` in 
`pakacge/src/routes/web.php`

`Route::get(config('app_settings.url'), 'SomeController')`

my tests are also giving 404 and `app_settings` config change is not getting picked by route.

```
function it_can_change_route_url_by_config() {
  // this should be default url
  $this->get('settings')
    ->assertStatus(200);

  // change the route url
  config()->set('app_settings.url', '/app_settings');

  $this->get('app_settings')
    ->assertStatus(200);

  $this->get('settings')
    ->assertStatus(400);
}
```

**app_setting.php**

```
return [
    'url' => 'settings',
    'middleware' => []
];
```

It works when I use this package, but tests fail.

Please help How I can give the option to change the route url from config.

Comment: show us app_setting config please

Comment: Aren't you missing here `get` after `Route::` in your code sample?

Comment: sorry Route::get was typo, @JulianMendez updated my question with config

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I think it's impossible to make such test. I've tried using some "hacky" solutions but also failed.

The problem is, when you start such test, all routes are already loaded, so changing value in config doesn't affect current routes.

**EDIT**

As alternative solution, to make it a bit testable, in config I would use:

```
<?php

return [
    'url' => env('APP_SETTING_URL', 'settings'),
    'middleware' => []
];
```

Then in `phpunit.xml` you can set:

```
<env name="APP_SETTING_URL" value="dummy-url"/>
```

As you see I set here completely dummy url to make sure this custom url will be later used and then test could look like this:

```
/** @test */
function it_works_fine_with_custom_url() 
{
    $this->get('dummy-url')
        ->assertStatus(200);

    $this->get('settings')
        ->assertStatus(404);
}
```

Probably it doesn't test everything but it's hard to believe that someone would use `dummy-url` in routing, and using custom env in `phpunit.xml` give you some sort of confidence only custom url is working fine;

Comment: you are right, I am also seeing the same issue. It works when you use this package, but tests fail, is there any way I can write a test for this.